# reusing a layout along with it's child components

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

[I have taken a look at android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts), but it doesn't give you any hint on how to override child component's properties using xml(nor programmatically, - I'd prefer `xml` at this point though).

Consider the following layout called `layoutBase.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/titlebar_bg"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" >

    <ImageView 
               android:id="@+id/myImageViewBase"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:src="@drawable/gafricalogo" />
    <TextView
               android:id="@+id/myTextViewBase"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have two other layouts called `layout1.xml` and `layout2.xml` where I'd like to *reuse* this layout using the `include` tag, but I'd like to do the following things, which [is not mentioned in the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts):

- The root `LinearLayout` can be given a different `id` but, how do I
  give a different `id` to both the `ImageView` and `TextView`after I
  include (using `<include ..>`) this layout in the `layout1.xml` and
  `layout2.xml`
- If I want the `ImageView` to contain different images in the
  `layout1.xml` and `layout2.xml` how do I change this property using
  the `<include ...>` tag?

Comment: You can't do either of those things with an `<include>`. The only things applicable on an `<include>` tag are the ID, and `layout_*` attributes. It sounds like you're wanting a custom/compound `View`, with which you can define an kind of attributes you want, and apply those to the inner child `View`s.

Comment: well, I don't know about writing a custom view, but, I want the exact same layout, only that it's text and image has gotta change. Do you think writing custom view is the only way to go, and does it include only xml or it should be done in java/kotlin ( I use java though)?

Comment: Just access views by ID in activity/fragment where you reused this layout and change content programatically, you don't need to change IDs.

Comment: No, that's not the only way, but any solution is going to involve some code, and a custom `View` is a common way to do this, as it keeps everything tidy, and somewhat less cumbersome than other methods. If you don't want to do that, then you could just find and modify the included `View`s in code. I'm not sure why you want the inner children to have different IDs, but as long as the parent `LinearLayout`s have distinct IDs, you can find those first, then find the children in them to modify.

Comment: @DmitriiLeonov , that's the problem , say I named the `ImageView` with id=xyz, then if I use the `include` to include it in `layout1` and `layout2`, I should access it by id, but both `layout1` and `layout2` have the same id.

Comment: @MikeM. , your comment " you can find those first, then find the children in them to modify" is the solution to what I was thinking. But, after things have been included using the `include`, if the parent have different id then the children are also different? I mean it's not like two different parents have the same children? Are the children also separate instances or would they be referring to the same instance because their `id` wasn't changed?

Comment: They will be separate instances. A single `View` instance cannot be in two places at once. They will have the same ID, but that's not inherently wrong or bad. You just need to manage it correctly. If these all end up in the same hierarchy, then it's just a matter of finding the parent `LinearLayout` first, with its distinct ID that was set on the `<include>`, then calling `findViewById()` directly on that `LinearLayout` to get its children. You're searching down the tree like that, so those children aren't going to get mixed up with the others in the different `LinearLayout`s. Follow?

Comment: you mean calling the root `LinearLayout` say `x` like: `x.findViewById(childrenId)`? But how would having the same Id refer to different instances, since they would refer to the same variable in `R` java file...?

Comment: `findViewById()` only searches down the hierarchy; i.e., it only searches children, and those children's children, etc.